# Creating virtual environment for python

Tags: python, virtualenv

While creating a virtual environment using the command `virtualenv myvenv`, I got the following error: `-bash: virtualenv: command not found`. What is the issue ?

```
ADITIs-MacBook-Air:~ aditinarware$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
ADITIs-MacBook-Air:~ aditinarware$ cd Desktop/Python_projects/
ADITIs-MacBook-Air:Python_projects aditinarware$ virtualenv myvenv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
ADITIs-MacBook-Air:Python_projects aditinarware$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Copy-paste it into the post instead.

Comment: It seems that the /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory is not in your $PATH variable. Try to add that to your $PATH in .bashrc and reload bash. Or you can run the virtualenv in that directory

Answer (score 0):

I cant see if you are trying to autocomplete the command, or you type it manually. I believe the script is called `virtualenv-2.7`.

To see if it really exists, just start typing (eg. `virtuale`) and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to see all available matching commands.